# Multiplot on multipages - ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to produce a pdf with multiple plots per page, and multiple pages long. 
I have used the [multiplot function](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_%28ggplot2%29/) to be able to plot multiple graphs on one page.

Using a loop I have created a list of plots and then called the list in the multiplot function to write it to a PDF.

```
status = dat$status

plotList <- list()
for (i in 2:31){
  ylabel= GeneID_Probe[2,i]
  IDlabel = paste("(",GeneID_Probe[1,i],")",sep ="")
  ylabel = paste(ylabel, IDlabel)
  plot = ggplot(dat, aes(x=dat[,1], y=dat[,i], color = dat[,1],shape = dat[,1])) + geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(0.2), cex =4.2)
  plot = plot + stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl, mult=1, geom="pointrange", color="red", cex = 1.2) +theme_minimal() +scale_color_brewer( palette = 'Dark2') + scale_x_discrete(labels=c("G1","G2"))
  plot = plot + ylab(ylabel) + xlab("") + theme(legend.position="none")
  plotList[[i-1]] <- plot
  print(plot)
}

pdf('eg.pdf', width = 8.3, height = 11.7) 
multiplot(plotlist = plotList, cols = 2)
dev.off()
```

Multiplot is attempting to plot all the plots in the list on one page.

My thoughts are that I could be able to split plotList into the number (6) of plots I want per pages. But I am sure there must be a way to do this with multiplot function?

Comment: if your not set on multiplot, you may find it useful to look at `marrangeGrob` from the `gridExtra` package. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33258000/plot-multiple-ggplot2-on-same-page and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352508/marrangegrob-giving-error-for-nrow have examples

Comment: No i am not set on using multiplot, I did play around with the gridExtra package but I couldn't get it to work. Will have a look at the links and hopefully be able to get it to work